# Is there a cookiecutter fork that generates a project template for CircleCI (instead of TravisCI)?

Tags: python, travis-ci, circleci, cookiecutter

I have been looking for a fork of the CookieCutter project (see https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html), which helps generate a python project template that automates building python apps and also generates a config file for CircleCI.

So far the templates generated have a `.travis.yml` file, I'd like a `.circleci/config.yml` instead.

I have been reading the docs on https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html and searching on the internet for alternative forks.

Currently, the project templates generate a `.travis.yml` file and we like to have a `.circleci/config.yml` file, when using the python `cookiecutter` CLI tool.

Comment: Have you considered creating your own fork?

Comment: I didn't want to reinvent the wheel and it seemed like there would be one for CircleCI given it's quite popular

Comment: @ManiSarkar if i search for "cookiecutter circleci", this question ranks lower than https://github.com/nolte/cookiecutter-circleci 

Comment: Thanks @michaeljoseph I'm certained I searched github for cookiecutter circleci but this repo didn't show up, I guess its my bad not searching hard enough!

Thank you for resolving this query!

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/nolte/cookiecutter-circleci

> Cookiecutter Template for a CircleCI, Continuous integration/Continuous delivery Pipeline, for different types of projects.